# How to update a Python library that is currently in use?

Tags: python

I have a few long running processes (FastAPI, Dagster, etc...) and it's not clear to me how I should handle updates.

I can just run `pip install {package} --upgrade`, and run it until it eventually works.

But is this the best way to handle it?

Comment: is this for production code or personal project?

Comment: For production I usually build a docker image and deploy it via a rolling update - this is more for testing locally.

Comment: This sounds really weird use case for any circumistance, especially for local testing when downtime doesn't matter one bit. You could probably hack something with importlib.reload etc, but runtime updates are prone to get into weird situations.

Comment: Which operating system? (On Windows, in-use files are locked; on UNIXy systems they aren't).

Comment: BTW, the way I would advise doing this involves not using `pip` _at all_, and instead using [Nix](https://nixos.org/) to assemble your software -- that way you _never_ replace anything that's in use; when you go from version X to X+1 in Nix they're installed in two different places; nothing ever changes in-place. (Similarly, the software that _uses_ dependency-X is installed in a different place from the software that _uses_ dependency-X+1, so the old tools with the old dependency chains still exist and don't get changed in-place either).

Comment: But the fact that folks can have opinions favoring a completely different software stack than the rest of the world is evidence that this is an opinion-based question and not really topical at all here :)

Comment: Not sure I agree. I have some local schedulers (Dagster, similar to airflow), and some long-running services (eg. streamlit). Ideally I'd like to know how to best update them without shutting them all down & restarting them - but it's not a big deal if this is not supported. Currently the services pick up the latest installed version when I restart them. Ps. I'm on windows.